# Bash Script MYSQL get columns from row

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to loop through some rows and display each column value from an MYSQL database in Bash.

An example of a row in the databse would be something like this:

```
Col1 = This is some Text
Col2 = This is other Text
Col3 = something-some
Col4 = TG
```

I'm using the following:

```
mysql -u$MUSER -p$MPASS -D$MUSER -e "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM tableName;" | while read col1 col2 col3 col4;
do

 echo "${col1}, ${col2}, ${col3}, ${col4}."

done
```

The problem I'm having with this is it's outputting the following:

```
This, is, some, Text This is other Text something-some TG.
```

It's like the reader is just looking for spaces.

Also, I've not been able to find much on using MYSQL with BASH. So if there are any good learning resources as well anyone could recommend that would be great too.

Comment: If you pass `--batch --raw --skip-column-names` it will give you tab-delimited columns

Comment: You will probably have to set IFS="|" before starting the loop

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Can you provide an example of that. I've tried putting in those switches but get the same results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing from "while read col1" etc to "while read -r output;" worked from an answer on stack exchange found here :

[Stack Exchange Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287042/mysql-output-format-in-bash-script/339526)